# Spring Boot 2 OAuth2 Resource Server Does not hit authorization server for access token validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Spring boot 2 + OAuth2 Oauthorization server.
I only want to use Client_credential to secure resource Server
I am able to get access token from Auth server, but when I pass this to access rest api, resource server does not validate it from authorization server and gives invalid access token error, I am using postman to get access token and to quest resource server.

**Authorization Server**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthorizationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorizationApplication.class, args);
    }       
}
```

Authorization server config

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SERVER_RESOURCE_ID = "oauth2-server";

    private static InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore).approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("clientABC").secret("{noop}secretXYZ")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .scopes("resource-server-read", "resource-server-write")
                .resourceIds(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

Authorization server web config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AuthorizationServerController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8090

logging:
  file: /logs/AuthourizationServer.log 
  level: 
    org.springframework: DEBUG
  pattern: 
      file: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID}){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx"
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

**Resource Server**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ResourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Web security config

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.WebEndpointProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceApplicationWebSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
    };

    @Autowired
    private WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()+"/health").permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/nonsecured").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Rest Controller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ResourceServerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/secured", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String securedResource() {
        return "This is Secured Resource";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/nonsecured", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String nonSecuredResource() {
        return "This is Non Secured Resource";
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8092
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8090/user
  basic:
    enabled: false
logging:
  file: /logs/ResourceServer.log 
  level: 
    org.springframework: DEBUG
  pattern: 
      file: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID}){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx"
```

Postman : getting token from Authorization server
[Postman : getting token from Authorization server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUNhV.png)

[Querying secured service and getting erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP1MG.png)

AuthorizationServer logs

```
2018-12-30 21:04:40.599  INFO 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.599  INFO 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.599 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2018-12-30 21:04:40.599 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2018-12-30 21:04:40.599  INFO 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.600 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-12-30 21:04:40.615 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.615 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'clientABC'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.631 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2018-12-30 21:04:40.742 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'scopedTarget.clientDetailsService'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-12-30T20:04:40.758Z, principal=clientABC, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null}]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@717e3c37: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@8e817097: Username: clientABC; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@717e3c37: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@8e817097: Username: clientABC; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@5a1c3cb4
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.758 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@717e3c37: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@8e817097: Username: clientABC; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
2018-12-30 21:04:40.773 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@76d8c502, returned: 1
2018-12-30 21:04:40.773 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2018-12-30 21:04:40.773 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2018-12-30 21:04:40.773 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2018-12-30 21:04:40.789 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/oauth/token", parameters={masked}
2018-12-30 21:04:40.790 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-12-30 21:04:40.842 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .s.s.o.p.c.ClientCredentialsTokenGranter : Getting access token for: clientABC
2018-12-30 21:04:40.858 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Found 'Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8' in response
2018-12-30 21:04:40.905 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583]
2018-12-30 21:04:40.920 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@38dba2a
2018-12-30 21:04:40.921 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2018-12-30 21:04:40.921 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-12-30 21:04:40.921 DEBUG 5144 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Resource Server logs

```
2018-12-30 21:04:54.158  INFO 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.158  INFO 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.158 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2018-12-30 21:04:54.159 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2018-12-30 21:04:54.159  INFO 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secured?access_token=087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secured?access_token=087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secured?access_token=087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secured?access_token=087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/secured'; against '/logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secured' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secured' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /secured' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /secured?access_token=087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2018-12-30 21:04:54.190 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2018-12-30 21:04:54.206 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583"
2018-12-30 21:04:54.206 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-12-30T20:04:54.206Z, principal=access-token, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Invalid access token: 087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583}]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.300 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@582fa201
2018-12-30 21:04:54.300 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 087b1986-b76e-4ff5-8e84-63ecd62e9583"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@29184e62]
2018-12-30 21:04:54.300 DEBUG 8512 --- [nio-8092-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

complete code is available in gihub
https://github.com/harsh-hardaha/springboot2Oauth2

Please ignore Admin server and swagger configuration code in github

Comment: Do you use the same token repository for authorization server and resource server?  You didn't configure a `token-info-uri`.

Comment: I have debugged code on Resource server side, and found that method public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) in 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager uses Defaulttokenservice which uses inmemorytokenstore in resource server side which is empty.

Comment: @dur No I do not use same token repository, both server are independent.
can you please let me know what will be implementation of  token-info-uri endpoint in authorization server side?

Answer (score 5):

After Some more inspection and debug I found Solution, I have to make below changes in resource server configuration 
Application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: clientABC
      clientSecret: secretXYZ
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8090/user
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:8090/oauth/check_token
      preferTokenInfo: true
      filter-order: 3
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

included dependency in resource server

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and adding the spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure dependency in resource server solved my problem.

My application.yml :

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8901/auth/user
```